# Pythonの公式日本語サイトについて

Tags: python

**下記はそれぞれどういう位置付けですか？**
・常に全く同一と考えて良いのでしょうか？
https://docs.python.jp/3/library/csv.html
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Python ドキュメント日本語訳プロジェクトの管理者の1人です.)

### TL;DR

> ・常に全く同一と考えて良いのでしょうか？

この問いへの回答は「常に全く同一であるとは限らない」です. (2017/11/01 時点, 2018/03/31 時点)

簡単にまとめると以下のようになります.

- docs.python.jp

  - 内容: やや古い
  - 翻訳: 最新 [2018/03/31 追記] ただし部分的に未訳の可能性あり
- docs.python.org

  - 内容: 最新
  - 翻訳: <del>やや古い (もしくは部分的に未訳)</del> [2018/03/31 修正] 最新

### 両者のドキュメントの違い

docs.python.jp と docs.python.org それぞれにある日本語ドキュメントの違いを説明します. (情報は <del>2017/11/01</del> 2018/03/31 時点のもの)

#### docs.python.jp

[PEP 545](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0545/) 以前の Python 2.x の頃から存在している翻訳プロジェクトによる日本語訳ドキュメントです.

本家のレポジトリを fork し, Sphinx の i18n 機能を使い翻訳を行っています.
日本語版用に一部カスタマイズが入っています.

fork の性質上, 本家 (docs.python.org) よりも古い内容になるのは避けられません.
極力本家のバージョンに追随するように更新作業を行っている状態です.

[2018/03/31 追記]
この更新作業は手で不定期に行っているので, 後述するように自動で更新している docs.python.org よりはやや古いものになります.

<del>ドキュメントは定期的にビルドされ, 1日に2回最新の HTML が公開されていくので,

翻訳の修正が反映されたものが12時間以内に公開されます.</del>

[2018/03/31 修正]
ドキュメントは定期的にビルドされ, 1日に2回 docs.python.org 用の飜訳が適用された HTML が公開されていきます.
docs.python.org と原文にズレがある箇所は, 飜訳が適用されず原文のままになってしまいます.

#### docs.python.org

[PEP 545](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0545/) によりホスティングされるようになった日本語訳ドキュメントです.

原文は最新のようです.
(このドメインのドキュメントは管理していないので, 更新タイミングについては詳しくないです.)

[2018/03/31 追記]
ドキュメントのビルド日付を見ると, 飜訳が更新されてからおよそ2, 3日以内には日本語ドキュメントに反映されているようです.
使用されている原文も最新のもののようです.

<del>翻訳は docs.python.jp で使用しているものを取得して使用していますが,

取得するタイミングが今のところ手動で不定期となっています.</del>

<del>そのため内容自体は最新ですが, 翻訳がやや古くなっていたり,

原文が変わってしまって翻訳が上手く当てられていないところがあるかもしれません.</del>

[2018/03/31 修正]
2018年の初めに, 原文の更新と最新の飜訳のアップロードを自動化したため,
ドキュメントビルドに数日のズレはあるものの, 基本的には docs.python.org の方が新しいものとなっています.

### P.S.

docs.python.jp で公開されるドキュメントは, その前の工程でいったん [GitHub Pages](https://python-doc-ja.github.io/py36/) にも公開されています.
翻訳の最新状況を確認したり, python.jp が止まっているときにドキュメントを参照したいときに便利です.

表現が分かりづらかったので追記 (2017/11/02): ビルドされたドキュメントを保存するためのレポジトリがあり, これが [py36](https://github.com/python-doc-ja/py36) レポジトリです. このレポジトリは GitHub Pages の設定がしてあるので, Web ページとして見れるようになっています.
python.jp への反映は, レポジトリから最新のビルド結果を取得するだけになっています. こういうワークフローになっているため, GitHub Pages の内容と python.jp の内容は (タイムラグはありますが) 同一です.

Comment: なるほど。翻訳に関しては常に「docs.python.jp」が最新だけれども、フォークした内容を翻訳しているため、タイミングはどうしてもズレてしまう、「docs.python.org」に関してはその翻訳を使用して、また異なるタイミングで更新している、というわけですね。ちなみに「いったん GitHub Pages にも公開」の「いったん」とはどういう意味ですか？　最終的なバージョンの前という意味？ それとも一時的にという意味？　あるいはそれ以外？？

Comment: はい, その理解で正しいです.
GitHub Pages へ公開する主な目的はビルド結果をレポジトリに保存することで, GitHub Pages としても見られるようにしています. python.jp への反映はこのレポジトリから pull するだけになっています.

Comment: 回答の本文に公開について追記しました.

Comment: 詳細回答＆追記ありがとうございました。

Comment: 2018/03/31時点の情報に更新しました.

Answer (score 10):

http://dsas.blog.klab.org/archives/2017-08/python-dev.html

> docs.python.org に言語スイッチのドロップダウンリストが追加されました。docs.python.org は Fastlyを使っているので、 docs.python.jp よりも高速に閲覧できると思います。
>
> docs.python.jp にあるセクション単位での英語ドキュメントへのリンク機能などがまだなくて単純な翻訳でしか無いので、すぐには docs.python.jp を止めるつもりはありませんが、将来的には docs.python.jp は docs.python.org/ja/ にリダイレクトすることを考えています。

Answer (score 2):

それぞれページの最下部右側に**最終更新日**がありますが、`python.jp`の方が新しいようです。

恐らく`python.jp`(日本ユーザ会)が原文の英語を翻訳、成果物が不定期に`python.org`に同期される
という流れではないでしょうか。

Comment: 翻訳ドキュメントが公式ページ配下に置かれているのは[PEP 545](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0545/)に準じた対応かと思います。